# VSExpress 2012 throws Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.PlatformNotFoundException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm doing Microsoft's basic introduction to creating a Windows Phone 8 app, creating a "MiniBrowser" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402526%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to get a feel of using VSE and debugging on my WP8 (Nokia Lumia 920). I have Windows 8 64-bit on my laptop (not Pro, so I realize I cannot utilize the emulators; this is therefore my only way of testing and debugging).

However, trying to deploy my app through Application Deployment and VSE 2012 (Deploy Solution under the Build tab, Debug tab under my project properties) gives me this strange error - "Exception of type Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.PlatformNotFoundException was thrown."

I have followed all the directions under "About deploying and running apps on a Windows Phone device" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx.

Googling and searching msdn and stackoverflow has not been successful, and it seems like no one else is encountering this problem. I feel like it should be a fairly simple and straightforward process to debug on my own phone... What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**: I downloaded the WP8 SDK and repaired my installation. I am no longer receiving this error.